# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-3

I am trying to learn to insert a simple record to a MySQL database using hibernate and I was following this [article](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/quick-start-maven-hibernate-mysql-example/) from Mkyong and I am stuck at the last step,i.e,when running App.Java.

Please help.Thanks in advance.

### pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibernateExample</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>HibernateExample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate framework -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate library dependency start -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate library dependency end -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

### Exception Stacktrace:

```
Maven + Hibernate + MySQL
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mkyong.persistence.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
    at com.mkyong.persistence.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at com.mkyong.common.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at com.mkyong.persistence.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:105)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/MethodFilter
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.javassist.BytecodeProviderImpl.getProxyFactoryFactory(BytecodeProviderImpl.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactoryInternal(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:77)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Hibernate 3.6.3.final the javassist runtime dependency is missing and must be added in your `pom.xml` as stated [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javassist-util-proxy-methodfilter/):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes,adding javassist runtime library to my pom.xml solved the problem and now I can successfully insert the record.Answer accepted. :)

Comment: Works even though nothing in my stacktrace mentioned anything about "javassist".

Answer (score 8):

I got this error when using Spring Boot 2.0.5 with Hibernate on Java 11 (JDK11).  To fix it, I had to force an upgrade of the javassist library (this is for Gradle):

```
compile('org.javassist:javassist:3.23.1-GA') {force = true}
```

For more info on migrating to JDK11, I found [this](https://medium.com/criciumadev/its-time-migrating-to-java-11-5eb3868354f9) blog post useful.  Alternatively, [upgrading to Spring Boot to 2.1 will fix this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14610).

Comment: Thanks. Saved my day!

Comment: Great thx, though, seems that 2.1.18.RELEASE still do not fix the problem :( :(

Answer (score 2):

javassist jar is missing in your project.

For ant based project just download it and put it in your libs

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavassistjar.htm

for maven projects use its repository, add its dependency

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javassist/javassist/3.12.1.GA

Answer (score 0):

The hibernate dependency even requires slf4j dependency. Try adding **slf4j dependency** in **pom.xml**